# C# data export to excel - error

Tags: c#

C# data export to excel - error

Hi all, hope in your help.

I am creating a C# 2010 Web application.

I have researched and test this and this should work...but I get an error and I can't get past this problem...my code below.

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem

CS0161: '_Default.GetData(System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand)': not all code paths return a value

```
private DataTable GetData(OdbcCommand cmd)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OdbcDataAdapter sda = new OdbcDataAdapter();

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            return dt;
        }
        else
        {
            string strScript = "<script>" + "alert('Not found!.');";
            strScript += "window.location='default.aspx';";
            strScript += "</script>";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Startup", strScript);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        sda.Dispose();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this before the closing bracket

```
return dt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the compiler already told you what your problem is.
You only return the `DataTable` if certain requirements are met.
However a non-void method most return something in all possible code paths.

Answer (score 0):

The if clause checking for rows in the data table excludes the rest of the method from returning the signature the method dictates to be returned. You most likely want to get rid of the if/else clause and just return the data table regardless of the row count. Your code calling the method should be doing the checking for row count and rendering the alert. I would also highly recommend using StringBuilder when concatenating strings like that... Or since the string seems to be static text, use it as such with a constant.